How to send a PDF file to share printer in PHP-Apache (Windows)
I swear I've searched for days and can't figure this out.
Network shared Printer Name: "\\192.168.0.100\Gprinter GP-3120TL"
Enter \192.168.0.100 through RUN (win+R), enter the username and password, double-click the printer to automatically download the driver and install it locally.
Environment: Apache 2.4, Windows(192.168.0.99), php 8.3
I have tried the following ways:
1.Use shell_exec() or exec(), If have an error the PHP script will be paused,Finally replace it with:
pclose(popen("start /B ". $commands, "r"));

2.Acrobat will left a GUI, Finally chose SumatraPDF.exe, Put it in the php script directory.
3.The final code is:
$printerPath = '\\\\192.168.0.100\\Gprinter GP-3120TL';
$fileToPrint = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "1.pdf";
$commands = "SumatraPDF.exe -print-to \"$printerPath\" -print-settings landscape \"$fileToPrint\" > C:/SumatraPDFlog.txt 2>&1";
pclose(popen("start /B ". $commands, "r"));

If echo $commands; and copied into cmd executed, it WORKING.
But in php Failed. Check C:/SumatraPDFlog.txt show: "No printer found"
I run this in php to check Printer list:
$printers = shell_exec('wmic printer get name');
echo nl2br($printers);

return:
Name
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax

If I run "wmic printer get name" in cmd, return:
Name
Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Microsoft Print to PDF
Fax
\\192.168.0.100\Gprinter GP-3120TL

Add SYSTEM permissions in printer properties-security tab, didn't work.
Add a printer in the printmanagement.msc, didn't work.
Add a printer in gpedit.msc, didn't work.
Change Service-Apache2.4-Login use admininstrator(default is SYSTEM)-WORKING.
WHERE I doing something wrong? Why can't SYSTEM access the network shared printer?

"Why can't SYSTEM access the network shared printer?" Such a question should be asked on https://superuser.com instead.

Thank you,I'll post on superuser.com
